# Use cout or cerr to output to console after it has been redirected to file

Tags: c++, stl

Redirecting cout or cerr to a file is easy enough. I can use this to redirect third party output to a file. However, after I have redirected the third party output to a file, how do I then use cout myself to output to the console?

Comment: What is "third party output"?

Comment: Typically debug chatter from code another team in the building wrote. I suppose I could poke them to give me an interface to have them output somewhere else. But I wanted to learn if there's another way to do it in case I came into a situation where I legitimately couldn't influence the code being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a great fan of RAII, so I once wrote this small helper class. It will redirect the stream until it goes out of scope, at which point it restores the original buffer. Quite handy. :)

```
class StreamRedirector {
public:
    explicit StreamRedirector(std::ios& stream, std::streambuf* newBuf) :
        savedBuf_(stream.rdbuf()), stream_(stream)
    {
        stream_.rdbuf(newBuf);
    }

    ~StreamRedirector() {
        stream_.rdbuf(savedBuf_);
    }

private:
    std::streambuf* savedBuf_;
    std::ios& stream_;
};
```

Can be used like this:

```
using namespace std;
cout << "Hello stdout" << endl;
{
    ofstream logFile("log.txt");
    StreamRedirector redirect(cout, logFile.rdbuf());
    cout << "In log file" << endl;
}
cout << "Back to stdout" << endl;
```

Comment: I like your use of anonymous scoping to take care of it. I was already using that for other RAII objects. Barring a better solution, I'd say this will have to do. It still doesn't solve other threads' use especially if there's no syncing mechanism for those threads.

Comment: Well, as long as the other threads do not change any of the `rdbuf`s, and you do the redirection before you call any potentially thread-spawning libraries, there should be no problem, I'd think? Unless I'm missing something here..

Comment: I think that would be implementation-dependent. I don't know of a guarantee that a thread gets its own copy of cout's state upon thread spawn?

Answer (score 4):

You save the buffer and restore it later:

```
std::streambuf *buf = std::cout.rdbuf(); //save
// Do other stuff
std::cout.rdbuf(buf); // restore
```

Comment: What if the third party lib has other threads which make calls to cout?

Comment: @inetknght: [See this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374264/is-cout-synchronized-thread-safe) for some more information about differences between C++03 and C++11, but basically you will have to manage synchronization yourself and make sure multiple threads are not writing to cout at the same time.