# Redirect debug output to null stream instead of std::cerr

Tags: c++, cross-platform, iostream

A software library that I am working with writes a lot of debug output to `std::cerr`, but redirects that output to a null stream if I tell it to be quiet. This is a simplified `main.cpp` that shows how the code tries to achieve this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>

// The stream that debug output is sent to. By default
// this points to std::cerr.
std::ostream* debugStream(&std::cerr);

// Throughout the library's codebase this function is called
// to get the stream that debug output should be sent to.
std::ostream& DebugStream()
{
    return *debugStream;
}

// Null stream. This file stream will never be opened and acts
// as a null stream for DebugStream().
std::ofstream nullStream;

// Redirects debug output to the null stream
void BeQuiet()
{
    debugStream = &nullStream;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  DebugStream() << "foo" << std::endl;
  BeQuiet();
  DebugStream() << "bar" << std::endl;
  assert(debugStream->good());

  return 0;
}
```

When you run this program, you will notice that the string "bar" is correctly sent to the null stream. However, I noticed that the assertion fails. Is this something that I should be concerned about? Or is this just a slightly ugly detail of the approach chosen by the library developers?

If you feel like it, suggestions for better alternatives are welcome. Some constraints:

- The library is cross-platform, so I think using opening `/dev/null` is not a valid solution as it would not work on Windows
- The library uses standard C++, so any alternative solutions should not use compiler-specific stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real need to be worried about the stream not being `good()`! Since the output operators don't really do anything wirh a stream in failure mode the different entities being logged are not formatted, i.e., the code does run faster compared to alternative approaches.

Note that you don't really need a second stream to disable output:

1. Assuming all output operators are well-behaved, you can just set `std::ios_base::failbit`:

   ```
   debugStream().setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
   ```
2. If there are misbehaved output which write to a stream even if it isn't `good()` you can just set its stream buffer to null:

   debugStream().rdbuf(nullptr);

If you really want your stream to remain in `good()` state, you'd install a stream buffer which just consumes characters. Note, however, that you want to give this stream buffer a buffer as having `overflow()` called for each `char` is fairly expensive. Also, overriding `xsputn()` is a benefit:

```
struct nullbuf
    : std::streambuf {
    char buf[256];
    int overflow(int c) {
        this->setp(this->buf, this->buf + 256);
        return std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
    std::streamsize xsputn(char const* , std::streamsize n) override {
        return n;
     }
};
...
nullbuf sbuf;
debugStream().rdbuf(&sbuf);
...
debugStream().rdbuf(0);
```

It is necessary to reset the stream's stream buffer because the destructor of an `std::ostream` will flush the stresm buffer (i.e., it calls `pubsync()`). Doing so on a destroyed stream buffer won't work.

Personally, I would go with setting `std::ios_base::failbit`.

Answer (score 3):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287777) you find a general helper to redirect any stream to any other stream:

```
class stream_redirector {
public:
    stream_redirector(std::ios& stream, std::streambuf* newBuf) :
        savedBuf_(stream.rdbuf()), stream_(stream)
    {
        stream_.rdbuf(newBuf);
    }

    ~stream_redirector() {
        stream_.rdbuf(savedBuf_);
    }

private:
    std::streambuf* savedBuf_;
    std::ios& stream_;
};
```

and now all you need is a no-op stream from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760301) which discards anything:

```
template <class cT, class traits = std::char_traits<cT> >
class basic_nullbuf: public std::basic_streambuf<cT, traits> {
    typename traits::int_type overflow(typename traits::int_type c)
    {
        return traits::not_eof(c); // indicate success
    }
};

template <class cT, class traits = std::char_traits<cT> >
class basic_onullstream: public std::basic_ostream<cT, traits> {
public:
    basic_onullstream():
    std::basic_ios<cT, traits>(&m_sbuf),
    std::basic_ostream<cT, traits>(&m_sbuf)
    {
        // note: the original code is missing the required this->
        this->init(&m_sbuf);
    }

private:
    basic_nullbuf<cT, traits> m_sbuf;
};

typedef basic_onullstream<char> onullstream;
typedef basic_onullstream<wchar_t> wonullstream;
```

and you're good to go:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cerr << "foo" << std::endl;
    {
        onullstream nos;
        stream_redirector sr( std::cerr, nos.rdbuf() );
        std::cerr << "bar" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cerr << "baz" << std::endl;
}
```

and finally here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b652b17c22c57fb) in case you want to play with it. This method has the additional benefit that you (and your colleagues) can still use `std::cerr` in your code and you can turn it off and on again at will :)

Comment: I didn't know coliru.stacked-crooked.com. Wicked!