# Redirect cerr using rdbuf: set it once and forget it until app ends

Tags: c++, stl, c++builder

I am attempting to redirect `cerr` to a file at the start of a program, then at the end of the program set it back to normal.  This is along the lines of the accepted answer of [Use cout or cerr to output to console after it has been redirected to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287777/)

I am running into strange behavior in C++Builder for this.  The environment seems to want me to refresh the stream redirection every time the program wants to output something.

I created the following test app to demonstrate the problem.  If I comment out the `#define` on the first line, I get memory access violations.  When the `#define` is uncommented, it seems to work fine while the program is executing; however, in a larger program, I believe I have also gotten the same memory access violations after the application terminates (works fine during execution with that `#define` in there – I still need to explore that one some more to track it down).

```
//#define MAKE_WORK

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include <fstream>
#include "TestRdbuf.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
std::streambuf* origBuff;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    std::ofstream oFile("ErrorLog.txt");
    origBuff = std::cerr.rdbuf();
    std::cerr.rdbuf(oFile.rdbuf());

    std::cerr << "Started: " << Now() << std::endl;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
#ifdef MAKE_WORK
    std::ofstream oFile("ErrorLog.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    std::cerr.rdbuf(oFile.rdbuf());
#endif

    std::cerr << "Closing:" << Now() << std::endl;
    std::cerr.rdbuf(origBuff);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
#ifdef MAKE_WORK
    std::ofstream oFile("ErrorLog.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    std::cerr.rdbuf(oFile.rdbuf());
#endif

    std::cerr << "Debug log time: " << Now() << std::endl;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::btnShowFileClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMemo * Memo = new TMemo(pnlBody);
    Memo->Parent = pnlBody;
    Memo->Align = TAlign::alClient;
    Memo->Font->Size = 12;
    Memo->Lines->LoadFromFile("ErrorLog.txt");
    Memo->ReadOnly = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
#ifdef MAKE_WORK
    std::ofstream oFile("ErrorLog.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    std::cerr.rdbuf(oFile.rdbuf());
#endif

    std::cerr << "Exit clicked: " << Now() << std::endl;

    Application->Terminate();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Wow, that's some obfuscated and convoluted code. I wouldn't want to work on that code-base.. Why all the `ifdef`s and all the `__fastcall` nonsense? Why the manual memory management? Why non-standard `pragma`?

Comment: `oFile` is a _local_ variable. It dies every time the current method terminates.

Comment: The #ifdef was my showing of a solution that I didn't want to use.  It turns out I was looking for something deep and missed the obvious - the local variable - thanks everyone.  The __fastcall and pragma are just C++ Builder standards (autogenerated in this case).  The OnCreate that Remy caught is new information to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, DO NOT use the Form's `OnCreate` event in C++. It is a Delphi idiom that introduces *undefined behavior* in C++, as it *can* be triggered *before* the Form's constructor, so use the actual constructor instead. Likewise, the Form's `OnDestroy` event *can* be triggered *after* the Form's destructor, so use the actual destructor instead.

Second, more importantly, `oFile` is a local variable. You are setting `cerr` to share the same `streambuf` object as `oFile`, but then `oFile` goes out of scope afterwards and is destroyed, which also destroys its `streambuf` object, leaving `cerr` holding a *dangling pointer* to invalid memory, hence the Access Violations.

You need to keep the `ofstream` object alive while `cerr` is sharing its `streambuf` object, eg:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include <fstream>
#include "TestRdbuf.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
std::ofstream oFile;
std::streambuf* origBuff;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    oFile.open("ErrorLog.txt");

    origBuff = std::cerr.rdbuf();
    std::cerr.rdbuf(oFile.rdbuf());

    std::cerr << "Started: " << Now() << std::endl;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::~TForm1()
{
    std::cerr << "Closing:" << Now() << std::endl;
    std::cerr.rdbuf(origBuff);

    oFile.close();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    std::cerr << "Debug log time: " << Now() << std::endl;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::btnShowFileClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMemo *Memo = new TMemo(pnlBody);
    Memo->Parent = pnlBody;
    Memo->Align = TAlign::alClient;
    Memo->Font->Size = 12;
    Memo->Lines->LoadFromFile("ErrorLog.txt");
    Memo->ReadOnly = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    std::cerr << "Exit clicked: " << Now() << std::endl;
    Application->Terminate();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```