# multiple threads writing to std::cout or std::cerr

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, valgrind

I have OpenMP threads that write to the console via cout and cerr. This of course is not safe, since output can be interleaved. I could do something like

```
#pragma omp critical(cerr)
{
   cerr << "my variable: " << variable << endl;
}
```

It would be nicer if could replace cerr with a thread-safe version, similar to the approach explained in the valgrind DRD manual (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html#drd-manual.effective-use)  which involves deriving a class from std::ostreambuf. Ideally in the end I would just replace cerr with my own threaded cerr, e.g. simply:

```
tcerr << "my variable: " << variable << endl;
```

Such a class could print to the console as soon as it encounters an "endl". I do not mind if lines from different threads are interleaved, but each line should come only from one thread.

I do not really understand how all this streaming in C++ works, it is too complicated. Has anybody such a class or can show me how to create such a class for that purpose?

Comment: please do not suggest printf.. ;)

Comment: *"This of course is not safe"* - This is not true in C++11, unless you take intentional action to make it true.

Comment: Your title says `cout` not `cerr`.

Comment: @AndyProwl I think what he means by "not safe" is interleaved as he says in the second part of the sentence.

Comment: @bamboon: Hm, makes sense. Although the OP wrote "It would be nicer if could cerr with a thread-safe version", which made me think he thought it is not thread-safe.

Comment: yes, maybe I used the term "thread safe" not correctly...

Comment: @Wolfgang: What is the problem with `printf` or `write`? Build the string in a stringstream, then use `printf`/`write` for an atomic write of the whole line...

Comment: @AndyProwl: Even in C++11 the code above involves multiple calls to `operator<<`, which means that the output of different threads can be mixed to produce: `myvariable: myvariable: 345` (now go figure whether the values are `3` and `45` or `34` and `5` :))

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes, I'm aware of that. I just meant to correct the statement about thread-safety.

Comment: Also see [Is cout synchronized/thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6374264/608639)

Answer (score 46):

As others pointed out, in C++11, `std::cout` **is** thread-safe.

However if you use it like

```
std::cout << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

with different threads, the output can still be interleaved, since every `<<` is a new function call which can be preceeded by any function call on another thread.

To avoid interleaving *without* a `#pragma omp critical` - which would lock everything - you can do the following:

```
std::stringstream stream; // #include <sstream> for this
stream << 1 << 2 << 3;
std::cout << stream.str();
```

The three calls writing 123 to the stream are happening in only one thread to a local, non-shared object, therefore aren't affected by any other threads. Then, there is only one call to the shared output stream `std::cout`, where the order of items 123 is already fixed, therefore won't get messed up.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for only operator<< calls being interleaved, as opposed to the individual characters?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374264/is-cout-synchronized-thread-safe suggests that it is "safe" in the sense of not causing a race, but may still result in interleaving.

Answer (score 14):

You can use an approach similar to a string builder. Create a non-template class that:

- offers templated `operator<<` for insertion into this object
- internally builds into a `std::ostringstream`
- dumps the contents on destruction

Rough approach:

```
 class AtomicWriter {
    std::ostringstream st;
 public:
    template <typename T> 
    AtomicWriter& operator<<(T const& t) {
       st << t;
       return *this;
    }
    ~AtomicWriter() {
       std::string s = st.str();
       std::cerr << s;
       //fprintf(stderr,"%s", s.c_str());
       // write(2,s.c_str(),s.size());
    }
 };
```

Use as:

```
AtomicWriter() << "my variable: " << variable << "\n";
```

Or in more complex scenarios:

```
{
   AtomicWriter w;
   w << "my variables:";
   for (auto & v : vars) {
      w << ' ' << v;
   }
}  // now it dumps
```

You will need to add more overloads if you want manipulators, you can use `write` better than `fprintf` for the *atomic write* in the destructor, or `std::cerr`, you can generalize so that the destination is passed to the constructor (`std::ostream`/file descriptor/`FILE*`),

Comment: I think I'd also add a `flush` member that does the same as the destructor and clears the internal buffer.  Then you can reuse the same atomic over and over if you wish.  Some people may prefer that to using extra scopes as in your second example.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Not sure what way to go... I understand what you ask for, but I find that the scope allows me to ignore the contents when I am looking at the logic and not the traces (our logging framework allows for similar constructs). That is, when used correctly (i.e. don't mix logic with logging), the scope can be used to analyze the contents and ensure that no real logic is there, after which I don't need to try to interpret what the internal loops are doing if I am looking at the logic of the whole function.

Comment: IMO This hides too much interesting logic in the destructor; making it hard to understand the consuming code; as indicated by the comment that indicates where the interesting stuff happens. Adding flush seems like a good idea except then it has two modes: explicit (flush) and implicit and that's confusing. And adding more overloads sounds like re-inventing the wheel. Expose the stringstream; or maybe just use that instead of defining a new class that does basically the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, but I wanted to post my addition to the AtomicWriter class to support std::endl and allow for other streams to be used besides std::cout. Here it is:

```
class AtomicWriter {
    std::ostringstream st;
    std::ostream &stream;
public:
    AtomicWriter(std::ostream &s=std::cout):stream(s) { }
    template <typename T>
    AtomicWriter& operator<<(T const& t) {
        st << t;
        return *this;
    }
    AtomicWriter& operator<<( std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&) ) {
        st << f;
        return *this;
    }
    ~AtomicWriter() { stream << st.str(); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in header file `atomic_stream_macro.h`

```
#ifndef atomic_stream_macro_h
#define atomic_stream_macro_h

#include <mutex>

/************************************************************************/
/************************************************************************/

extern std::mutex print_mutex;

#define PRINT_MSG(out,msg)                                           \
{                                                                    \
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock (print_mutex);                 \
                                                                     \
    out << __FILE__ << "(" << __LINE__ << ")" << ": "                \
        << msg << std::endl;                                         \
}

/************************************************************************/
/************************************************************************/

#endif
```

Now the macro can be used from a file as follows.

```
#include <atomic_stream_macro.h>
#include <iostream>

int foo (void)
{
    PRINT_MSG (std::cout, "Some " << "Text " << "Here ");
}
```

Finally, in the main.cxx, declare the mutex.

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex print_mutex;

int main (void)
{
    // launch threads from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by inheriting [`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), and override the correct functions to make it threadsafe. Then use this class for your stream objects.