# Do c++ standard output streams respect the order of the calls in a multi-threaded application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, iostream

I know that we will never see something like this

aabb**ABAB**aabb

as the output of the following code

Thread1

```
std::cout << "aa";
```

Thread2

```
std::cout << "bb";
```

By the way, will the writes be atomic if we add an endline to the previous calls like this?

Thread1

```
std::cout << "aa" << std::endl;
```

Thread2

```
std::cout << "bb" << std::endl;
```

Anyway, the single writes are atomic. So my question. Will it always hold that if thread1 requested a write before thread2, then we will see message "aa" before "bb"? If we know this always holds, it makes sense to log entries about the state of a multi-threaded application to be able to examine deadlocks and etc.

Other words, is it possible that Thread1 calls `cout` first, but the actual message it requested to appear in the stream appeared **only after** Thread2 got its version of writing to stream executed. To me, this scenario is quite possible, if, for example, **right after** `cout` was called, but actually **before** it was completely executed,there happened a context switch, and Thread2 was given enough time for both requesting `cout` and having low-level os-dependent library actually execute Thread2's request. Correct me please if I am wrong and this scenario is not possible

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033827/multiple-threads-writing-to-stdcout-or-stdcerr

Comment: No, `std::endl` won't help, it's still two separate calls. I'm not sure if there's any utility to guarantee that two threads will not get I/O intertwined (you'd have to lock it manually). Your best bet might be printing timestamps together with your actual message.

Comment: how do you know that "thread1 requested a write **before** thread2" without synchronisation mechanism? with some synchronisation the question is moot, because then the order is well defined

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 That's the point of this question I think? "*If* Thread1 reaches `std::cout <<` line first, is it guaranteed that it will also output first"?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes, but the notion of "thread1 reaches the line first" only makes sense when it can be determined which thread comes first and I wouldnt know how to do that without using a mutex or similar

Comment: My question was about being able to actually **tell who's first** with the help of logging. I know that the order of threads reaching `cout` is not defined in general, because the threads that are not in sync with each other are said to be racing and it is not certain who reaches `cout` first. But there is always someone who is THE first, so I am asking if I can tell who is first with the help of the output messages? I mean, is it possible that thread1 **called** `cout` first, but the actual message was delivered after thread2's message?

Comment: In a race scenario, the notion of "called `cout` first" doesn't make too much sense. It's always possible that the function call _started_ earlier in thread 1 but then got preempted immediately, thread 2 runs the whole function and then thread 1 completes.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, this totally makes sense, thanks, this answers my question, as I have now updated it. Can you write an answer?

Comment: Btw, according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374264/is-cout-synchronized-thread-safe#comment7469304_6374525), you might actually get abab. A given C++ implementation might not allow that (and I don't know whether the comment is actually correct), but you should be careful. In any case, it's at least not a data race since C++11 so no UB.