# Mutex in Operating System

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, mutex

**Does the Mutex mechanism comes into picture at the time of Console input/output in c/c++?**

I mean, will the Console Stream be protected by Mutex and get locked/unlocked by threads in usual way?

Comment: Why not try it?  Start two threads that do nothing except console output in a loop.  If you get output from both threads, it's protected bya lock of some sort, perhaps a mutex.  If you process crashes, there is is no lock.

Comment: Is this what you are asking? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6374264/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes wrapping output with a `std::mutex` will make sure that separate threads don't access the stream at the same time.  Individual calls to `cout` when it is synchronized with stdio(default behavior) is safe although no guarantee is given on the order in which characters from multiple threads are inserted.

Consider

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mx;

void print(char ch, int count)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mx);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << ch;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}   

int main() {
     std::thread t1(print, 'x', 10);
     std::thread t2(print, '*',20);

     t1.join();
     t2.join();
     return 0;
}
```

With the mutex the output is([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e45367c1f774ba58)):

```
xxxxxxxxxx
********************
```

And without the mutex one possible output is([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57d297db9c521433)):

```
xxxxxxxxxx********************
```

Comment: it means by default the console stream wont be handled by mutex or locked/unlocked by the same thread ?

Comment: @NadeemBhati if the call to `cout` comes in between a `mutex.lock()` and mutex.unlock()` then they will print in the order the threads are executed.