# Two threads blocking on I/O

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Let's consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
int main()
{
    std::thread t1([](){
        int a;
        std::cin >> a;
        std::cout << "T1: " << a << std::endl;
    });
    std::thread t2([](){
        int a;
        std::cin >> a;
        std::cout << "T2: " << a << std::endl;
    });


    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with: `g++ -std=c++14 -pthread main.cpp -o main`
Run with: `./main < file.txt`

file.txt:

```
1 2
```

The outputs are different ( I supposed so), for example:

```
T1: T2: 12

    T1: 1T2: 
2

T1: 12
T2: 0
```

and so on.

I suppose that code causes undefined behaviour? Am I right? 
And how to solve/explain situation when two threads try use the same ( ? ) input/output?

Comment: The behavior is well-defined. But recall that C++ describes a *non-deterministic* abstract machine. Each one of those outcomes is equally valid. You may observe different outcomes on different runs of the same program.

Comment: It's undefined in C++03 and earlier (as in, the standard doesn't mention anything about it), but defined and well-behaved in C++11 and later ([see e.g. this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6374525/440558)).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , it is very interesting what you said ( I mean "C++ describes a non-deterministic abstract machine"). Please tell me more / reference me somewhere. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This program is not a valid C++03 program to begin with (observe the use of `std::thread`), so appealing to C++03 is rather pointless.

Comment: "**[intro.execution]/1** The semantic descriptions in this International Standard define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract
machine..." "**[intro.execution]/5** A conforming implementation executing a well-formed program shall produce the same observable behavior as one of the possible executions of the corresponding instance of the abstract machine with the same program
and the same input..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe to access standard [input](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) and [output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) streams as long as they are synchronized with C-streams (their default state). However output (and input) might be interleaved if you do not use any means to prevent simultaneous access.

> **27.4.1/4**        [iostream.objects.overview]
>   Concurrent access to a synchronized standard iostream object’s formatted and unformatted input and output functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall not result in a data race. [ *Note: Users must still synchronize concurrent use of these objects and streams by
>   multiple threads if they wish to avoid interleaved characters. —end note* ]