# flushing cout buffer working correctly while cerr dosent

Tags: c++

Im trying to print some error messages in my code, and I need to show the error immediately when they appear, 
Using it like this works :

```
> cout << "erroe msg" << endl;
```

But with cerr the print isnt consestent

```
> cerr<< "error msg" << endl;
```

Isnt `endl` on `stderr` flush the buffer the same way it dose with `stdout` ?

minimal example :

```
int uthread_block(int tid){
    block_alarm();
    if(tid == 0){
        cerr <<"thread library error: You cannot block the main thread\n" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

This function is used sometimes while going throw 100 thread in my program and sould be print an error message in a specific time. If ill change `cerr` to `cout` it will be correct at the time, and with `cerr` it can be show at the start of the output the end or the middle ( probable when it flushing the buffer)

Comment: `cerr` is unit-buffered anyway; i.e. it will be flushed at every write operation. What makes you think it isn't being? Please provide a full [mcve] with details of how you are running your program.

Comment: Please define "the print isnt consestent"

Comment: the print of the message can be at the start of the output the end or the middle, but when changing to cout it in the right place

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just a threading issue, because if your other threads are outputting then the order things will be printed isn't defined unless you've put mutexes etc in

Comment: The other thread are printing, but what makeing me think it is in the cerr is because im just changing it and working as expected. (And btw the threads printing is a tester that should work).

Comment: You haven't demonstrated the problem. This may have some helpful info  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374264/is-cout-synchronized-thread-safe