# How to write to file from different threads, OpenMP, C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I use openMP for parallel my C++ program. My parallel code have very simple form

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(a, b, c) private(i, result)
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
         result= F(a,b,c,i)//do some calculation
         cout<<i<<" "<<result<<endl;
         }
```

If two threads try to write into file simultaneously, the data is mixed up.
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Synchronization

Comment: Don't write in multiple threads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OpenMP provides pragmas to help with synchronisation.  `#pragma omp critical` allows only one thread to be executing the attached statement at any time (a mutual exclusion critical region).  The `#pragma omp ordered` pragma ensures loop iteration threads enter the region in order.

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fopenmp critical.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    std::cout << "unsynchronized(" << i << ") ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    #pragma omp critical
    std::cout << "critical(" << i << ") ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  #pragma omp parallel for ordered
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    #pragma omp ordered
    std::cout << "ordered(" << i << ") ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Example output (different each time in general):

```
unsynchronized(unsynchronized(unsynchronized(05) unsynchronized() 6unsynchronized() 1unsynchronized(7) ) unsynchronized(unsynchronized(28) ) unsynchronized(unsynchronized(93) ) unsynchronized(4) 10) unsynchronized(11) unsynchronized(12) unsynchronized(15) unsynchronized(16unsynchronized() 13unsynchronized() 17) unsynchronized(unsynchronized(18) 14unsynchronized() 19) 
critical(5) critical(0) critical(6) critical(15) critical(1) critical(10) critical(7) critical(16) critical(2) critical(8) critical(17) critical(3) critical(9) critical(18) critical(11) critical(4) critical(19) critical(12) critical(13) critical(14) 
ordered(0) ordered(1) ordered(2) ordered(3) ordered(4) ordered(5) ordered(6) ordered(7) ordered(8) ordered(9) ordered(10) ordered(11) ordered(12) ordered(13) ordered(14) ordered(15) ordered(16) ordered(17) ordered(18) ordered(19)
```

Comment: In case of just writing data to a file, using the last method ordered,can there be speedup ? I am asking because for me it looks if threads are exectuting the loop in order then it is equal to a serial execution right ?

Comment: @AdityaG possibly there can still be parallel speed up, as the ordered pragma doesn't need to apply to the whole loop body, for example: `#pragma omp parallel for ordered \n for int (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) { do parallel work; #pragma omp ordered \n { do ordered serial output; } do more parallel work; }`

Comment: I tested your code, for the case of just writing. I have no "do parallel work" but only a ordered statement in the for loop. What ever I do inside this ordered pragma, the parallel one is always slow (only a bit though). This approach can only be helpful if there is a good amount of work to be done in parallel compared to the work inside ordered pragma.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is: you have a single resource all threads try to access. Those single resources must be protected against concurrent access (thread safe resources do this, too, just transparently for you; by the way: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374525/1312382) is a nice answer about thread safety of std::cout). You could now protect this single resource e. g. with a `std::mutex`. Problem then is, that the threads will have to wait for the mutex until the other thread gives it back again. So you only will profit from parallelisation if F is a *very* complex function.

Further drawback: as threads work parallel, even with a mutex to protect std::in, the results can be printed out in arbitrary order, depending on which thread happens to operate earlier.

If I may assume that you want the results of F(... i) for smaller i before the results of greater i, you either should drop parallelisation entirely or do it differently:

Provide an array of size `N` and let each thread store its results there (`array[i] = f(i);`). Then iterate over the array in a separate non-parallel loop. Again, doing so is only worth the effort if `F` is a complex function (and for large N).

Additionally: Be aware that threads must be created, too, which causes some overhead somewhere (creating thread infrastructure and stack, registering thread at OS, ... – unless if you can reuse some threads already created in a thread pool earlier...). Consider this, too, when deciding if you want to parallelise or not. Sometimes, non-parallel calculations can be faster...